# Bayesian nonparametric estimate of median

Tags: bayesian, quantiles, median, credible-interval, nonparametric-bayes

I've been working on estimating the population median of a variable with a complex distribution that is not easily characterized as a parameterized probability distribution. So far, the best I have come up with has been obtaining confidence intervals with bootstrapping.

How could I calculate a credible interval instead? I've been learning Bayesian data analysis but this problem is beyond my skills at the moment. Does it even make sense to try to apply Bayesian analysis to this problem?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Please give use some information on 1) the actual problem you're studying (the research question, the population, the experiment design, sample size, etc.) and 2) the complex distribution you're talking about (show a histogram, boxplot, etc.).